# How I can assert that returned response has the expected data?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have the following route:

```php
Route::get('/records', function(Request $request) {
    $page = (int) $request->get('page');
    $limit = (int) $request->get('limit');

    return new JsonResponse(\App\Model\Record::paginate($limit, ['*'], '', $page), 200);
});
```

And I made the following unit test:

```php
use App\Model\Record;
use Tests\TestCase;

class RecordsEndpointTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testRecordsFetched()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/records?page=1&limit=10');
        $response->assertStatus(200);

        Records::factory()->count(100)->create();

        $expectedRecords = Records::paginate(10, ['*'], '', 1)->items();

        foreach ($expectedRecords as $dbRecord) {
            $response->assertJson(function(AssertableJson $json) use ($dbRecord) {
                $json->has('data', 10, function(AssertableJson $json) use ($dbRecord) {
                    $json->where('id', $dbRecord->id)
                        ->where('name', $dbRecord->name)
                        ->where('surname', $dbRecord->surname)
                        ->where('birth_date', $dbRecord->birth_date)
                        ->where('death_date', $dbRecord->death_date)
                        ->where('agency', $dbRecord->agency)
                        ->where('country_of_operation', $dbRecord->country_of_operation)
                        ->etc();
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But once I run it I get the following error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\Routes\SpyRoutesTest::testGetSpiesNoFilters
Unexpected properties were found on the root level.
Failed asserting that two arrays are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-Array &0 ()
+Array &0 (
+    0 => 'current_page'
+    2 => 'first_page_url'
+    3 => 'from'
+    4 => 'last_page'
+    5 => 'last_page_url'
+    6 => 'links'
+    7 => 'next_page_url'
+    8 => 'path'
+    9 => 'per_page'
+    10 => 'prev_page_url'
+    11 => 'to'
+    12 => 'total'
+)

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/Fluent/Concerns/Interaction.php:44
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php:648
/var/www/html/tests/Feature/Routes/SpyRoutesTest.php:213
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:174
```

What I try to do is to check that the response Json at `data` section the records returned are the same as the one that the paginated query would return.

Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: Is this truly working `Records::factory()->count(100);`? You did not call `create` or `make` (`Records::factory()->count(100)->create()`), so you should have nothing at all created. That is why you get an error saying `expected = nothing at all, actual = you got something back (only the pagination data because you have no data at all)`

Comment: And remember to create those models BEFORE you call `$this->get`, else you execute the controller with already no data in your database

Comment: As I said, you still have the creation AFTER you execute the controller, so you will never have data available, you have to move `Records::factory()->count(100)->create();` before `$response = $this->get('/records?page=1&limit=10');`